# How to get header request in nodejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, authentication, express

Currently developing the elasticsearch API application, I need to get the header request from AJAX call in server side. Ajax request given below.

```
$.ajax({
          url: 'http://localhost:3002/api/v1/getAutoSuggest/'+elasticsearchIndex+'/'+elasticsearchType,
          dataType: 'JSONP',
          type: 'GET',
          beforeSend: function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader('access-control-request-headers', 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9');},
          success: function (data) {

          }
});
```

In nodejs, I tried to get by using **req.headers['x-access-token']** but couldn't get it.

```
var checkToken = app.use(function(req, res, next) {
var token = req.param.token || req.headers['x-access-token'];

  if (token) {
    jwt.verify(token, config.secret, function(err, decoded) {      
      if (err) {
        return res.json({ success: false, message: 'Failed to authenticate token.' });    
      } else {

   req.decoded = decoded;    
        next();
      }
    });

  } else {
  }
});
```

And also I have added the following statements in nodejs server side.

```
 var allowedOrigins = ['http://127.0.0.1:8000', 'http://localhost:8000', 'http://127.0.0.1:9000', 'http://localhost:9000'];
     var origin = req.headers.origin;
     if(allowedOrigins.indexOf(origin) > -1){
       res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', origin);
     }

    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, OPTIONS');
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'access-control-request-headers');
    res.header('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
```

But getting token in lowercase `eyjhbgcioijiuzi1niisinr5cci6ikpxvcj9` .

Thanks in advance!

Comment: req.headers['x-access-token']  works for me

Comment: what console.log(JSON.stringify(req.headers)) return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set headers when using `JSONP`. The reason for that is because when using `JSONP` for cross domain requests, jquery implements this by injecting a special `<script>` tag into the DOM in order to load the remote resource. And as you know, when using `<script>` tags you have no way of specifying custom headers.

An alternative approach to `JSONP` would be to use [`CORS`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS). The server will need to support it and explicitly allow the origins and headers that need to be set.